# No access to Facebook user/live_videos even though I have user_videos permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have approved access to Facebook user_videos permission. This is supposed to give me access to the user/live_videos endpoint. However when my users hit this endpoint the exception is returned from Facebook.

(#10) To use live-video-api on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

If I hit this endpoint with my account I can access my live video just fine. But not with other users who have authorized access to the user_videos permission.

Approved permission 
[image]

Why would I not be able to access the users live videos using `$fb->get('/{user-id}/live_videos'`?

Instead I get the exception.

Comment: That sounds like they want you to submit for review of the _feature_ Live Video API as well, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-LIVE_VIDEOS The description there indicates that was only necessary for _creating_ live videos, but it migh be necessary to read them as well?

Comment: Right, that does sound like what they want but it does not make sense to list a common end point to be users/live_videos for the user_videos permission if it does not work.